# Error while installing opencv-python in virtualenvironment with python 3.9 on macOS Catalina

Tags: python, macos, numpy, pip, opencv

I am trying to setup a virtual environment, named `deeplearning`, for, euh, a deep learning project :-) on my MacBook Pro with macOS Catalina.

Within the `deeplearning` virtual environment I did `pip install opencv-python` but this throws an error, which I don't understand... How do I fix it? Am I overlooking something?

Looking at the last bit of the whole error output it seems it is trying to match different `numpy` version to a specific `python` version. `Python 3.9` is not among them. Is this the issue? Should I revert to version `Python 3.8`?

I installed `python@3.9` and `numpy` with `brew`.

Thanks

Sander

```
pip install opencv-python
Collecting opencv-python
  Using cached opencv-python-4.4.0.44.tar.gz (88.9 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/swvanderlaan/.virtualenvs/deeplearning/bin/python /Users/swvanderlaan/.virtualenvs/deeplearning/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/kc/c5rw4cb94c1c149gsm2ygfc00000gn/T/pip-build-env-mudxxq4k/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel scikit-build cmake pip 'numpy==1.11.3; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"'' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"''
       cwd: None
  Complete output (4098 lines):
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.5"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7"' don't match your environment
```

> [I could not post everything due to the character limit.]

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/swvanderlaan/.virtualenvs/deeplearning/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/kc/c5rw4cb94c1c149gsm2ygfc00000gn/T/pip-install-we6wxt_t/numpy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/kc/c5rw4cb94c1c149gsm2ygfc00000gn/T/pip-install-we6wxt_t/numpy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/kc/c5rw4cb94c1c149gsm2ygfc00000gn/T/pip-record-wdchzme9/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /private/var/folders/kc/c5rw4cb94c1c149gsm2ygfc00000gn/T/pip-build-env-mudxxq4k/overlay --compile --install-headers /private/var/folders/kc/c5rw4cb94c1c149gsm2ygfc00000gn/T/pip-build-env-mudxxq4k/overlay/include/site/python3.9/numpy Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/swvanderlaan/.virtualenvs/deeplearning/bin/python /Users/swvanderlaan/.virtualenvs/deeplearning/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/kc/c5rw4cb94c1c149gsm2ygfc00000gn/T/pip-build-env-mudxxq4k/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel scikit-build cmake pip 'numpy==1.11.3; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"'' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.
```

And update. This extends to installing: `scipy`, `scikit-learn` and `scikit-image` - they are all dependent on `numpy`. Which has been installed also with `pip3 install numpy`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Python 3.9` is just a few weaks old and it looks like there is no binary package available for `OpenCV`. So `pip` is trying to compile it from source, which obviously fails, as it has many dependencies.

I suggest you install `Python 3.8` for now and upgrade to `Python 3.9` in a few weeks / months, when all the common packages are available on `pip`.

Comment: Right. I suspected as much. So I probably need to setup my `brew` environment properly. It now install `Python 3.9` because `cairo` needs the latest version, or at least the `stable 1.16.0 version from `cairo` needs that. Any thoughts on how to tackle this?

Comment: This is a good read: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/switch-python-3.9/